# UITextView set content offset

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to set content offset of uitextview, but if it's big - it isn't working. Have you any ideas?

My code

```
[myTextView setText:@"very long .... text"];
[myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,4000)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
yourTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0);
```

OR

```
yourTextView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score -1):

*Usually we `doesn't need to set content offset`. if the text in textview is more it will automatically creates scroll property in it .
Textview size will be same but the text in it is scrollable. if it is not scrolling make sure `UITextViewDelegate` is set*

Comment: He is asking about contentOffset not contentSize.